# Custom Format for Current Date and Time in C++

Tags: c++, datetime, datetime-format

I am trying to save a file into a directory of files based on the **current** date and time. I am trying to get the format of the following:

1. "FullMonth-FullYear" example:
   "April-2011"
2. "FullMonth-littleDay-year" example:
   "March-7-11"
3. hour-minutes-seconds. example: "18:05:09" in 24 hour format

Comment: But I'm looking to input it into a string. would Strftime work for strings?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the format you have the time in right now. I'm a big fan of `sprintf()`, and since I mostly deal with big piles of seconds, milliseconds, or nanoseconds, I do a lot of modulus arithmetic to get what I want.

Answer (score 0):

[boost](http://www.boost.org/).[date_time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/date_time/doc/index.html) can do arbitrary formatting, to a higher a degree of precision than the standard functions are typically capable of. Specifically, see [Date Time Input/Output Format Flags](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.format_flags).